# XenForo SEO Friendly URL returns 404 on forum page

Tags: seo, htaccess, apache, ubuntu

I have my .htaccess file in the base directory of the installation of XenForo. When I enable SEO Friendly URLs, it returns error 404 only on the forums and members pages.

htaccess file:

```
#   Mod_security can interfere with uploading of content such as attachments. If you
#   cannot attach files, remove the "#" from the lines below.
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#   SecFilterEngine Off
#   SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 405 default
ErrorDocument 406 default
ErrorDocument 500 default
ErrorDocument 501 default
ErrorDocument 503 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    RewriteBase /

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

when looking at the links when SEO Friendly URLs is enabled/disabled the index.php? is gone, which it's supposed to do but it can't seem to find the forums...

Comment: "only on the forums and members pages" - so the "friendly URLs" (without the `index.php`) work OK on other pages? (You seem to have disabled friendly URLs across your whole site at the moment? ...I'm wondering why you are linking to it?)

Comment: I have members trying to figure out why my servers are down, can't access it without the forums. I'll enable it now, won't do much good.

Comment: Ah, so it's not "only on the forums and members pages" - it's on **all** friendly URLs. (?) Remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper. Any errors?

Comment: None in apache or Xenforo's logging.

Comment: Is `FollowSymLinks` enabled? Try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` to the start of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Enabled, no change and no errors.

Comment: Are `.htaccess` files enabled?! Try adding any _junk_ at the start of the file... do you get an error? (500 Internal Server Error is expected).

Comment: Apparently not, no error whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently not, no error whatsoever.

It seems that `.htaccess` files are not allowed/enabled on your server, since adding some random text to the file produces no error. (You would expect to see a 500 Internal Server Error otherwise.)

You need to set `AllowOverride All` (or something more restrictive like `AllowOverride FileInfo` - enough for mod_rewrite) in your server config (`<Directory>` container) that covers the document root directory.

However, if you have access to the server config then you can do all of this in the server config and not use `.htaccess` at all (recommended).

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

---

**UPDATE:** And then if it's still not working, repeat the checks as mentioned in comments above:

- Is mod_rewrite enabled? Remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper - do you get an error? If mod_rewrite is not enabled then expect to see a 500 Internal Server Error (your error log should contain the specific details of the error). You need to [enable mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) and restart Apache.
- Is `FollowSymLinks` (or `SymLimksIfOwnerMatch`) enabled? This is required for mod_rewrite to work. Add `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the top of your `.htaccess` file.

If you are still seeing an *Apache generated* 404 message then then "something else" is going on, since the URL is not being rewritten. (Your `.htaccess` file looks "OK".)

If you are seeing a 404 generated from your framework (XenForo) then the problem is with your application.

Comment: I have enabled htaccess files, the file with random text now produces errors. I have loaded the backup file I made before making any changes. I am still unable to access the forums and members pages.

Comment: You have an issue with XEN then, not mod_rewrite.

Comment: Repeat the checks as mentioned above (in comments). Are you still getting an Apache generated 404 message (it appeared to be when I checked a short while ago) - this would imply you still have an Apache config issue. If, however, you are getting a 404 generated from your application then the problem is now with your application (as Simon suggests). I've updated my answer.